How to match the wmi camera names with cv2 camera index
With wmi i can find the camera names (like HP True Vision HD).
How to match this camera names to cv2 indexes?
There is a missmatch trying to match.
Is there any alternative? (for example list camera true names with cv2 directly)?

No.  The concept of a "camera name" is mostly a Windows concept, just as WMI is.  If you're using a DirectShow backend, you may be able to fetch the backend object and query some DirectShow properties.
